# Check connection for RODBC Connection (Scope issue)

Tags: r, database

I'm trying to use the following code to check if my RODBC connection is open (and to open/re-open it if it is not).

```
check.connect <- function(channel) {
  connected <- FALSE;
  while (!connected) {
    tryCatch( 
      { sqlQuery(channel, "SELECT * FROM deb.table LIMIT 1;");
        print('Success')
        connected <- TRUE },
      error=function(e) {
        print('Reconnecting');
        channel <- odbcConnect('SQLConn')
     })
   }
 }
```

This becomes an infinite loop. The sqlQuery line errors and 'Reconnecting' is printed until I abort with ctrl+c.

I imagine this is a scoping issue, but I am not sure and do not know how to solve it. Additionally, once I get 'Success' to print, will I have to return the new channel or will the changes be reflected in the channel object in the calling scope.

Comment: have you come up with any solution for this problem?

Comment: infinite loop is result of network problems - when you can't reconnect due to broken link, etc. your code will be re-trying as long as problem persists. My suggestion is to re-try once and ten return error (stop).